# How do I acces attributes from an object, inside a List, in the same class?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, attributes

I want to acces the variables from an object from the class the object is  intitialized in. I've tried using objectName.atrr and I've tried using a get method. With both methods when I type "testObject." the atrributes don't show up in the list of possibilities nor does the get method get shown as an option.
How do I acces attributes from an object, inside a List, in the same class?

```
public class State{
 // This is the constuctor
 Point sPos;
 int sID;
 int sRot;
 List listState = new ArrayList();

 public ClassName(Point shape_Pos, int shape_ID, int shape_Rot){
    sPos = shape_Pos;
    sID = shape_ID;
    sRot = shape_Rot;        
 }
 //here are the get methods
 public int getID() {
    return sID;
 }
 public Point getPos() {
    return sPos;
 }
 public int getRot(){
    return sRot;
 }
 public void methodName(){
   //here is code that creates States and add it to listState (left it out)
   currentState.add(new State(new Point(0,0),1,1));
   ...
   Object testObject = currentState.get(0);
   System.out.println("testObject = "+testObject);

   //This is not working
   int id = testObject.sID;
   // This is also not working
   int id2 = testObject.getID();
 }
}
```

OUTPUT: // Like I expected and wanted, same as the object inside the list

```
Object = State@1ae73783
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using generics:

```
List<State> listState = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then treat your `testObject` like an instance of `State`, not `Object`:

```
State testObject = currentState.get(0);
```

When you declared `testObject` as `Object  testObject = currentState.get(0);`, you are telling the compiler to handle `testObject` as an instance of `Object`. It will not have access to any of the members or methods of `State`.

Comment: testObject.sID isn't public so assuming that everything else in the code works, the code will still error.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using State but got an error, because I forgot to make it a list of <State>. That was kinda stupid of me ;). It works now!

Comment: @user2173361 if the answer works, you should mark it as correct

Comment: I had to wait 7 min before I could click on the correct sign. Now I did that right?